# python-websocket and socket.io namespace

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io

I would write a websocket client in python to connect to a server written with socket.io.
My current code, taken from [1](http://gist.github.com/1402238) is the following:

```
import websocket, httplib, sys, asyncore
def connect(server, port):

    print("connecting to: %s:%d" %(server, port))

    conn  = httplib.HTTPConnection(server + ":" + str(port))
    conn.request('POST','/socket.io/1/')
    resp  = conn.getresponse() 
    hskey = resp.read().split(':')[0]
    ws = websocket.WebSocket(
                'ws://'+server+':'+str(port)+'/socket.io/1/websocket/'+hskey,
                onopen   = _onopen,
                onmessage = _onmessage,
                onclose = _onclose)

    return ws

def _onopen():
    print("opened!")

def _onmessage(msg):
    print("msg: " + str(msg))

def _onclose():
    print("closed!")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    server = 'localhost'
    port = 8081

    ws = connect(server, port)

    try:
        asyncore.loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ws.close()
```

My question is how do I connect to a specific namespace?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [socketIO-client](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client) which is available on PyPI under the MIT license.  It has support for different namespaces of a single socket.

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, BaseNamespace

class MainNamespace(BaseNamespace):

    def on_aaa(self, *args):
        print 'aaa', args

class ChatNamespace(BaseNamespace):

    def on_bbb(self, *args):
        print 'bbb', args

class NewsNamespace(BaseNamespace):

    def on_ccc(self, *args):
        print 'ccc', args

mainSocket = SocketIO('localhost', 8000, MainNamespace)
chatSocket = mainSocket.connect('/chat', ChatNamespace)
newsSocket = mainSocket.connect('/news', NewsNamespace)
mainSocket.wait()
```

Comment: For those of you using this, I believe the format's change slightly recently. Read the docs if you're getting stuck. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client

Answer (score 1):

You can change the namespace more easily.

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, BaseNamespace
socket = SocketIO('192.168.4.47', 7777)
chat = socket.define(BaseNamespace, '/openchat')
chat.emit('echo', 'hello openchat my name is Anderson')
```

I've solved this problem in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client

hope you save your time a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use Wireshark to sniff a connection made with Socket.IO and that you send the correct packets through your websocket connection to fake being a Socket.IO client.. and then implement the packets and messaging protocol of the Socket.IO layer.

There is basic documentation of the packet types in here:

http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/packet.html#module-socketio.packet

Also, you can read the test suite that shows the wire-level protocol (that you will probably need to implement):

https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/blob/master/tests/test_packet.py

A specific namespace is specified in the packet of different types as you will see in the docs.

Hope this helps.